# How can I make a page reloading in the middle of the process using PHP?

Tags: php

Here is my code:

```
public function save_problem(Request $request)
{
    $doesnot_turn_on = isset($request->doesnot_turn_on) ? $request->doesnot_turn_on : "";
    $res = setcookie('guarantee_ticket', json_encode(["title"=>$request->problem_title, "description"=>$request->problem_description, "turn_on" => $doesnot_turn_on, "unique_product_id" => $request->unique_product_id]), time() + 200000, "/");
    if ( Auth::check() ){
        return $this->register_guarantee_ticket();
    } else {
        return \redirect()->route('short_register',["des" => route('register_guarantee_ticket')]);
    }
}

public function register_guarantee_ticket()
{
    $problem = json_decode($_COOKIE['guarantee_ticket']);

    .
    .
```

As you can see, when `Auth::check()` is `true`, then `register_guarantee_ticket()` will be called while still `$_COOKIE['guarantee_ticket']` isn't defined and it (cookie) needs a page reloading to be defined.

How can I make that page reloading with PHP?

I know `header("Location: ...")` will be used for redirecting. But how can I keep the process and do also a redirect?

Comment: `header("Location: ...")` does — not — stop the execution of the rest of the `script`.

Comment: Don't use cookies, simple as that.

Comment: @emix If the user isn't logged in, it will be to a registration form and I need to keep that data in the cookie.

Comment: This is wrong method. If you will reload then you have to call the same function `save_problem` again either by clicking or submitting a form or using jquery. But reloading the page twice for one user action will not look good.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is why you need reloading the page while the request is processing (that's impossible in HTTP mechanism)

So I have an idea for you to fix this (by passing cookie data to sub-function) :

```
public function save_problem(Request $request)
{
    $doesnot_turn_on = isset($request->doesnot_turn_on) ? $request->doesnot_turn_on : "";
    $cookie_data = ["title"=>$request->problem_title, "description"=>$request->problem_description, "turn_on" => $doesnot_turn_on, "unique_product_id" => $request->unique_product_id];
    $res = setcookie('guarantee_ticket', json_encode($cookie_data), time() + 200000, "/");
    if ( Auth::check() ){
        return $this->register_guarantee_ticket();
    } else {
        return \redirect()->route('short_register',["des" => route('register_guarantee_ticket')]);
    }
}

public function register_guarantee_ticket($cookie_data)
{
    $problem = $cookie_data; // No need this assign, but I put it here to point out you should pass cookie data directly to sub-function

    .
    .
```